# Clear search field on focusout

Tags: javascript

When I search my list after focus out, the input field is cleared but search is still on, after backspace then search is clear how I handle this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.btnSelect', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
    var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
    var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
    var data = `<tr>
                    <td>${col1}</td>
                    <td>${col2}</td>
                    <td>${col3}</td>
                    <td>${col4}</td>
                    <td><button class="deleteBtn">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>`;
    document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML += data;

    // $('#data').focus(function() {
    //     $(this).val('');
    // });

    rfunction();
    // clears(target);
    // alert(data);

  });
});

function clr(x) {
  x = '';
  document.getElementById("data").value = '';
}


function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").classList.toggle("show");
}

function rfunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myTable").classList.toggle("show");
  element.classList.remove("show");


}

function fadi() {
  let filter = document.getElementById("data").value.toUpperCase();
  let myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let tr = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      let textvalue = td.textContent || td.innerHTMl;

      if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
  filter = null;
}

// var index, table = document.getElementById("mytable");
// for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
//     table.rows[i].cells[4].onclick = function() {
//         index = this.parentElement.rowIndex;
//         table.deleteRow(index);
//         console.log(index);
//     };
// }
// for delete
const tableEl = document.getElementById('mytable');

function onDeleteRow(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('deleteBtn')) {
    return;
  }
  const btn = e.target;
  btn.closest("tr").remove();
}
tableEl.addEventListener('click', onDeleteRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" id="data" onclick="myFunction();" onkeyup="fadi()" onfocusout="this.value = ''" placeholder="Enter Product Here..." onfocusin='clr(this)'>
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question. The **title** should be short. The **code** should be formatted as a Code Snippet  `<>`. You have all the necessary tools in the question editor. Read [ask], and create a [mcve]. And since you didn't, please take a [tour].

Comment: Please fix your console errors in the snippet I made you. You need to add more HTML for a [mcve] Also try to add more details, perhaps using Google Translate